# Php MySQL updating a column only if IP is new

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make my script update the view count by +1 everytime a IP is new.
and after 604800 seconds, if the same user(same IP) comeback again after 604800 seconds view count by+1.
Can someone help me out here.

```
//Get video id
$id = $_GET['id'];
//Get video title
$videoName = $_GET['idtitle'];



//Connect to database
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=videodb', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

//Get user IP
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

//Insert that user IP, Name, Title and increase view count by +1
//This is what i want to accomplish but is not working!
$insert = $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos` ( `ip`, `name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$ip', '$id', '$videoName', `views`+1)");
```

// Sample Two

```
//Select the IP from videos
$select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `ip` FROM `videos`");
$sql = $select->execute();
while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
//If the IP in database is not equal to the user IP in database views +1
if($row->fetch('ip') == $ip){
 $pdo->query("UPDATE videos SET `views` = `views`+1 WHERE id = '$id' ");
 }}
```

Comment: You are using PDO, why not binding the params then? Way more secure!

Comment: Because everytime i try to do anything with PDO:: i always get some type of error and my database will not be collecting visitor input all i need is a way to check if user ip is new or old and if is new update the views count.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more column in your table as last_viewed_at DATETIME.

**Now before inserting the record into the database:**

As you are checking the the record for the last 7 days then query as like below:

```
$row = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE 
id = 'users.ip.to.check'";
```

**Conditions:** You have got record against the `users.ip.to.check`
now check whether the time difference is more than 7 days.
means.

```
if (count($row) > 0) {
    $ipLastViewAt = new \DateTime($row['last_viewed_at']);
    $currentDate = new \DateTime();

    $diff = $currentDate->diff($ipLastViewAt)->format("%a");
    if ($diff >= 7 ) {
        // update the record with the view + 1 and with last_view_at = currentDateTime;
    }  
} else {
    // Insert the record with the view +1 and with last_view_at = currentDateTime;
}
```

Comment: When i try your code i keep getting an error on 
    $ipLastViewAt = new \DateTime($row['last_viewed_at']);    ->  

  
      Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Comment: Because you are using the PDO object as array. don't use that directly.
Try with $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE 
id = 'users.ip.to.check'");
$select->execute(); $row = $select->fetch();

Answer (score 0):

## **is not a full code,just for your information!**

Tips:two tables maybe better,one save video info,another save visitor info

```js
videos:id,ip,name,title,views,update_time

// first, select $video info and get the result --- "select * from videos where ip='{$ip}' and id='{$id}'";
// we got $video look like : array('id'=>1,'update_time'=>'1453970786') 

$time = time();
if( isset($video['id']) && (($time - $video['update_time']) >= 604800) ){
 $pdo->query("UPDATE `videodb`.`videos` SET `views`=`views`+1 AND update_time='$time' WHERE id = '$id'");
}elseif( !isset($video['id']) ){
 $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos`( `ip`, `name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$ip', '$id', '$videoName', 1)");
}
```

**edit**

```js
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos`(`id`, `ip`, `name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$id','$ip', '$id', '$videoName', 1)");
```

Comment: is working but for some it still not adding +1 to views count.  It just keep adding entry.

Comment: $pdo->query("INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos`(`id`, `ip`, `name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$id','$ip', '$id', '$videoName', 1)");

Answer (score 0):

If Ip is unique field then this query should help

```
INSERT INTO `videodb`.`videos`( `ip`, `name`, `title`, `views`) VALUES ('$ip', '$id', '$videoName', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `views`=views+1;
```